# Add several html form fields to a list before submission?

Tags: java, html

I'm new to HTML and I've created a webpage with a form that submits to a URL that uses the input as parameters in a call to a java function. It starts off with a few simple text inputs, for example:

```
<input type="text" id="Title" maxlength="128" placeholder="Max 128 characters" required/>
<textarea id="Description" maxlength="1999" placeholder="Max 2000 characters" required></textarea>
```

The part I'm struggling with is the last parameter, which is a list of a unique data structure that takes four parameters itself.  Currently, I have fields set up to create one instance of the structure as such:

```
<select id="IdNumber" onChange="changeTextBox();">
<input type="text" id="Value"/>
```

Submission works perfectly fine when the forms corresponding to the data type are filled, but the page needs to support submission of multiple sets of this data type.

Ideally, what I want to do (and I've seen this feature on webpages before) is create an "Add" button that when clicked, adds the values of the "IdNumber" and "Value" fields to the submission, then clears these fields and allows further additions to the submission. I've done some research into this and have been unable to find anything of use.

Is there any way to store groups of input as some sort of object structure in html? Or if not, can someone point me in the right direction to solving this problem some other way? Thanks!

Comment: Very unclear what you mean. What you write does not seem to be reflected in the snippets you post

Answer (score 0):

1. i think you should add the 'name' attribute to your fields. this is how values are usually mapped.
2. if i understand you right, what you're trying to accomplish here is a checkbox-like behaviour, only in a more unique way. if this is the case, write a quick test that includes checkboxes. you'll see that they all go by the same name so when you post the form you get a list of values attached to the name of the checkboxes. [here's](http://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_checkbox) an example.